# Error Trying To Get Property Of Non-Object In Laravel 5.6

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

so I am trying to loop through an array of objects to update certain values in my database with the values from the object

When I run this loop in my controller

```
foreach($statuses as $status){
            $workflow->statuses()->where('id', $status->id)->update([
                'status' =>  $status->status
            ]);
        };
```

It gives me error `trying to get property of non-object`

When I do a `return response($request->statuses) this is the data structure I see in the console
[image]

here is the complete controller

```
public function workflowStatuses(Request $request, Workflow $workflow)
    {

        // validate form data
        $data = $request->validate([
            'workflow' => 'required|string',
        ]);

            // validate form data
        $oldStatuses = $request->validate([
            'statuses' => 'required|array'
        ]);

        // validate form data
        $newStatuses = $request->validate([
            'newStatuses' => 'required|array',
        ]);


        $workflow->update($data);

        $statuses = $oldStatuses;

        foreach($statuses as $status){
            $workflow->statuses()->where('id', $status['id'])->update([
                'status' =>  $status->status
            ]);
        };

        $workflow->statuses()->saveMany($newStatuses);

        return response($workflow, 200);

    }
```

Comment: What does it show if you call dd($workflow->statuses());

Comment: maybe each status is an array, try `$status['id']` instead of `$status->id`

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `$statuses` instead of `$request->statuses`?

Comment: @Younel, I get alarm saying `Undefined index: id`

Comment: @Devon, well my data is coming from ajax, so maybe I should post the entire controller to give better perspective. Please see update for entire controller.

Comment: Can you update your ques with code above this loop? What actually u r doing with $request

Comment: @Manpreet, please see updated post

Comment: do a dd($statuses); before loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the return value of `$request->validate()` as the array of all request input filtered to only include the data that's being validated.  If that validated data contains arrays, you'll have a multi-dimensional array.

Here, `$oldStatuses` is going to be an array that contains a key named `statuses` that contains the actual array you're looking for.

```
$oldStatuses = $request->validate([
   'statuses' => 'required|array'
]);


// $statuses should get 'statuses' out of this validated array
$statuses = $oldStatuses['statuses'];
```

Instead, you may want to clean this up and not call validate three times.  It's usually better to run all the validation rules in one validate() call, unless you have good reason to logically separate them.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
   'workflow' => 'required|string',
   'statuses' => 'required|array',
   'newStatuses' => 'required|array',
]);

$statuses = $validated['statuses'];
```

Comment: that seems to have done the trick!, and I was not aware that `'statuses'` in the validation could be called later as `$statuses`. With that in mind I will update the controller

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($statuses as $status){
   $workflow->statuses()->where('id', $status['id'])->update([
   'status' =>  $status['status'] //$status['status'] should also be accessed by key 
   ]);
};
```

Comment: I get this alarm `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: Then you should do a dd($statuses) check you array structure and use keys accordingly.

Comment: is that not what I am doing with `return response($request->statuses)`?